# Python Reading Lines

Tags: python

I am trying to get this program to read a file and find the color red. Works only if the color red is on any line but the first one otherwise detects it as red not found.

```
filepath = sys.argv[1]
with open(filepath,"r") as fh:

    for line in fh:

        line = line.strip()
        line = line.lower()
        words = line.split(" ")

        for word in words:
            if re.search("red", word):
                print("I found red")
                break
            else:
                print("I did not find red")
                break
```

Comment: the inner for loop isn't needed just search over `line`

Comment: Also consider using `if 'red' in line:`, if you are doing something this simple, regex is seriously overkill.

Comment: By removing the `break` in the `else` it should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

There are enough comments that at this point we should just put it as an answer to compile it.

1) `re.search` goes through an entire line, so you don't need to do a `for word in words`, just do `re.search('red', line)`, though you should also compile the regex expression since you use it in a for loop.

2) `re.search` is overkill for your problem. You can just use `in`.

Consider the following version of your code as a cleaner solution:

```py
filepath = sys.argv[1]
with open(filepath) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        # strip isn't needed since we are doing containment checking
        if 'red' in line.lower():
            print("I found red")
        else:
            print("I did not find red")
```

If you want to use regex because you actually have a different use-case you aren't showing than do something like this:

```py
import re

filepath = sys.argv[1]
FIND_RED = re.compile(r'red', re.IGNORECASE) # ignore cases and compile to make it faster if used a lot.
with open(filepath) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if FIND_RED.search(line):
            print("I found red")
        else:
            print("I did not find red")
```

Answer (score 0):

A more pythonic way:

```py
filepath = sys.argv[1]
with open(filepath, "r") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        print("I found red" if "red" in line.lower() else "I didn't found red")
```

Answer (score 0):

Search the entire file before *saying* you haven't found it.

```
filepath = sys.argv[1]
found = False
with open(filepath,"r") as fh:

    for line in fh:

        line = line.strip()
        line = line.lower()
        words = line.split(" ")

        if 'red' in words:
            found = True
            break
if found:
    print("I found red")
else:
    print("I did not find red")
```